# Why is there a NullPointerException in the output?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was learning Threads , and I'm stuck up on this program, why is this resulting in NPE? why do the threads not run?

here's my code:

```
class Chicks {
        synchronized void yack(long id) {
        for(int x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.print(id + " ");
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}
class ChicksYack implements Runnable {
    Chicks c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChicksYack().go();
    }
    void go() {
        c = new Chicks();
        new Thread(new ChicksYack()).start();
        new Thread(new ChicksYack()).start();
    }
    public void run() {
        c.yack(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should initiate `Chicks c` in every new created `ChicksYack`

Comment: when you start a new thread then `Chicks c` is a new instance and it is not initialize on that thread

Comment: create the instance in the run method, eg:     public void run() {
        c = new Chicks();
        c.yack(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

Comment: Does this mean , c=new Chick(); inside go() method creates Chick instance only for main thread and not for other two threads?

Comment: @Codeninja yes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Iscoughlin